# Looping an animation using Bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm new to Bokeh and Python, and this is my first Stack Overflow question as well.

I'm using Bokeh to plot trajectory profiles of particles diffusing in the brain, but have it be animated.  I have been able to successfully create a program that plots the points, but once all the points are plotted, it stops.  I want to be able to loop the animation so that once all the points are plotted, it clears itself and starts over.

I am still very unfamiliar with coding terms, and I wasn't able to find something that could do this.  I thought I was on the right track with importing using the reset function inside an if statement, but it doesn't seem to work.  I have looked at the following as well for reference:

[How to animate a circle using bokeh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31008714/how-to-animate-a-circle-using-bokeh)

Here is my code so far plotting a random trajectory:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, gridplot, vplot, hplot, curdoc
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
from bokeh.client import push_session
from bokeh.core.state import State as new

# This is where the actual coding begins.
b = np.random.rand(300, 3)
xlist = b[:, 1]
ylist = b[:, 2]

# create a plot and style its properties.  Change chart title here.
p = figure(title='PEG_PLGA15k_F68_R2_P81', title_text_font_size='13pt',
       x_range=(min(xlist), max(xlist)), y_range=(min(ylist), max(ylist)),)

# add a text renderer to out plot (no data yet)
r = p.line(x=[], y=[], line_width=3, color='navy')

session = push_session(curdoc())

i = 0
ds = r.data_source


# create a callback that will add a number in a random location
def callback():
    global i
    ds.data['x'].append(xlist[i])
    ds.data['y'].append(ylist[i])
    ds.trigger('data', ds.data, ds.data)
    if i < xlist.shape[0] - 1:
        i = i + 1
    else:
        new.reset()

# Adds a new data point every 67 ms.  Change at user's discretion.
curdoc().add_periodic_callback(callback, 67)

session.show()

session.loop_until_closed()
```

Comment: `p` is missing from `session.show()`, so correct function call is `session.show(p)`, otherwise no plot is shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to restart the animation once you reach some condition (like "all points have been plotted") you can just reset the DataSource. So, for instance, on your example you should have:

```
else:
    i = 0
    ds.data['x'] = []
    ds.data['y'] = []
```

instead of:

```
else:
    new.reset()
```

and that should do the trick. Just use your datasource... `State` is a more general component that should be used on different level and not to manage plot glyphs and datasources.

A couple of quick notes here:

1. On your question you've mentioned a link to the `0.10` version documentation but from your code I can tell you are not using a newer version (`0.11.x`). Always be sure to use the right docs for the version of Bokeh you are using since there might be a few changes between one version and another before the project reach `1.0`.
2. You don't need to call `ds.trigger('data', ds.data, ds.data)` since bokeh property system will automatically detect your changes to the datasource fields inside your callback
3. You are designing/running your script as a bokeh script that uses a client session to the server (so you'll have a running instance of bokeh server somewhere and your script communicates with it). I'd suggest you to  consider running your code as a Bokeh App instead, so your session and your code run inside the bokeh server instance. You can see more details about the difference at the [bokeh server section on the official docs](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html).